# Is it possible to generate alert or any UI before incoming and outgoing calls and texts in android

Tags: android, alert

In my application I need to generate an alert or something of that kind which asks the user for confirmation before outgoing and incoming calls and texts. I'm done with `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` and I can just `Toast` a msg.

Comment: Explain more what you want to do and what you did. The general path is to use a broadcast receiver for that. But showing a custom UI when a user has some other action to do quickly is generally a very very very bad idea.

Comment: I just want to make the user to reconfirm whether he really want to make the call to some particular numbers(which the application takes from user initially) and i have used the broadcastreceiver to open my application on an outgoing call but i could not pause the calling process... help me out please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ITelephone.aidl and place events to listen the phone state. I am helping you for the Telephone calls handling (Including a short snippet about how to disconnect it).  SMS also happens in similar way.  It would be best if you can research and figure out about it

```
import com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;

public class CallMonitor 
{
    protected StateListener phoneStateListener;
    //stops the service to monitor any call.  
    public void stopMonitor()
    {
        try
        {
            TelephonyManager telephonymanager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            telephonymanager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
            phoneStateListener=null;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Call Monitoring Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { 

        }       
    }

    public void startMonitor()
    {
        try
        {
            phoneStateListener = new StateListener();
            TelephonyManager telephonymanager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            telephonymanager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Call Monitoring Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) 
    {
        return null;
    }


    class StateListener extends PhoneStateListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) 
        {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            switch(state)
            {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:

                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        try
                        {   
                            TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                            Class c = Class.forName(manager.getClass().getName());
                            Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                            m.setAccessible(true);
                            ITelephony telephony = (ITelephony)m.invoke(manager);
                            telephony.endCall();
                        } 
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Error ending the call" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Permissions are

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help kishu.. but it has worked out more efficiently using BroadcastReceiver..

Comment: thanks for letting me know @Kishore, can you help me understand what exactly made you convinced of the BroadcastReceiver's efficiency.  In my app this code lets the phone ring for 1/4 second then handles it.  What have you observed?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... Actually the process of BroadcaseReceiver is that the intent before performing the action will broadcast the respective message. So the BroadcastReceiver is triggered before the action is performed.. therefore before ringing i'm able to handle the call.

Comment: But the problem is i'm unable to handle outgoing SMS... please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked in this area before but I think, You can use [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) interface.. which will invoke functions as the phone state changes....The [**Telephony Manager**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) might be useful too.

Just a try from my side hope that helped,